CodenameOne duplicate dependencies
I'm using CodenameOne in IntelliJ, and when I tried to run, it said that there was 'duplicate dependencies'. I have a couple of other errors in my app's common pom.xml as well. They are all as follows:
"Dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlin.version} not found"

"Plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:${kotlin.version} not found"

"Plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:${kotlin.version} not found"

"Cannot resolve symbol 'exec.mainClass'"

"Cannot resolve symbol 'cn1.mainClass'"


Since a few of the issues had to do with Plugins, I tried to go to the Plugin Marketplace, however the Marketplace had not loaded, though internet does not seem to be an issue.
This is my first time using CodenameOne, and I am still navigating the waters, so I am not sure if this issue is common or not.

How did you create the project? Did you use start.codenameone.com? Can you include the full error? You can create a github gist with the full error log.

Yes, I used start.codenameone.com, where I downloaded a Bare-bones Java App. The 'CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar' file was not included in this, so I downloaded it elsewhere. Additionally, here is the shareable link to the github gist with the error that comes when I run: link

If you're using Kotlin why did you download the barebones Java app and not the barebones Kotlin app?
